# Rotation of rigify doesn't work even with modified weights

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, geometry, rigify

I have made a model of a cartoon character with a pointy nose but unfortunatly when I applied automatic weights it didn’t work properly so I then changed those weights and it works for most of the body exept the head, especialy when rotating the head, the nose does a weird thing where only a part of it moves, I have tried multiple times to change it, modify weights, switch to different bone layers ect… Could anyone help me ?
here are some pictures to better understand the issue ;
[image: Neckbone weight]
[image: Headbone weight]
[image: Tophead weight]
[image: View of the issue]
[image: View without rotation]

I have yet to finish refining the weights on the model and I might come back with more issues I can’t solve.
If you wish to help me in any way, thank you.

Comment: @TheLabCat There isn't any weight assigned from the neck bone to the nose :( even when I double checked by making sure the neck bone wasn't affecting the nose, it still didn't work properly. [link](https://imgur.com/a/3rcenFS)

Comment: just a guess: Have you checked the normals/face orientation?

Comment: @Blunder they are all facing the right way [link](https://imgur.com/a/uIMUlxG)

Comment: hm, well, it was worth a try. Can you share a file with the head and the rig? That would make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: @Blunder Sure, how do I send the file ?

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share it or google drive, dropbox or wetransfer.com. You need to post here the link then.